# Chaining Include statements in Entity Framework query

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is the below a correct way to eager load `Entity Framework` entities from related tables:

```
from item in _context.entity1
    .Include("childentity1.childentity2")
    .Include("childentity1.childentity3")
where item.id == 1;
```

Object hierarchy is

- entity1 (many) - (one) childentity1
- childentity1 (many) - (one) childentity2
- childentity1 (many) - (one) childentity3

I am unsure if chaining the `Include` statements should be done this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite. It should be:

```
from item in _context.entity1
    .Include("childentity1.childentity2")
    .Include("childentity1.childentity3")
where item.id == 1
select item;
```

Note the final `select` clause. Without it the program won't compile. Other than that your statement will work as you expect.

You may also want to use an alternative syntax, which allows strong typing so you can avoid a run-time error in case you misspell something:

```
from item in _context.entity1
    .Include(x => x.childentity1.childentity2)
    .Include(x => x.childentity1.childentity3)
where item.id == 1
select item;
```

You'll need `using System.Data.Entity;` for that. In addition, if you doubt your entity has really been eagerly loaded, you can try something like the following:

```
_context.childentity1.Local.Count()
```

which will tell you how many `childentity1` objects have been loaded into the context.

Comment: Nice. I actually had the Select there but  copy-paste to here get screwed.